# Flexible branching/list datastructure?

Tags: java, data-structures

I need a flexible structure for holding data anywhere in a tree structure for exporting to JSON later. My actual data could be anywhere in that tree. Here is the structure I'm talking about.

```
-1
  -1.1
    -Data
    -Data
    -..
  -1.2
    -Data
    -Data
    -..
    -1.2.1
      -Data
      -Data
      -..
-2
  -Data
  -Data
  -..
  -2.1
    -2.1.1
      -Data
      -Data
```

Data can come in anywhere in the tree. The numbers should eventually be readable strings. Once serialized to JSON these should go into other applications as roll-out lists.

I have the following:

```
public class Branch {
    String name; //Substitute for the numbers
    Branch deeperBranch;
    ArrayList<Data> data;
}
```

Another thing I want to make sure of is that whenever a duplicated `Branch.name` is created it goes into the existing `Branch`. Am I reinventing the wheel here and would this be a efficient way of tackling the problem I'm facing?

Comment: how would your current structure support 1.1, and 1.2 being on same branch? wouldn't you need a list or map of String/Branch

Comment: The numbers in your example  (1.2, 1.2.1 etc) are inherently hierarchical and structured. Are your strings the same way?

Comment: @BrandonLing It's basic, but I lookup if the branch name exist in that branch. If it does I add to it's list.

Comment: @Arkadiy No my strings can be anything but logical for a human. Most are preset names to choose from but the user has the ability to add to it in special occasions.

Comment: @Madmenyo Right, but looking up if a branch exists implies there can be multiple branches for a single branch which yours will not be able to do. I think my answer provided should illustrate what I'm talking about. I made an edit to make it a set instead of a map

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a structure that is conveniently created for your needs. With that said, I think it's fairly trivial to create:

```
public class Branch {
    String name; //Substitute for the numbers
    Set<Branch> subBranches;
    List<Data> data;
}
```

I made it a `Set` because you want to keep the names unique, however, you would have to implement something to recursively check to see if it exists. Additionally you would need to implement `equals` method.

I also changed `ArrayList` to `List` since it's good programming practice to code to an `Interface`

Comment: I read your comment and it's a great solution but I have to work around the replacing behavior of `Map` since it needs to add when it exists. I think I can dump the name field since that would be the key in the map.

Comment: Ok, there is a reason to keep the name field.